# What can be a one-word substitute for the phrase "past present and future "?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I need a one word substitute for "past present and future" which can be apt for a title of a magazine (college)

Comment: ***Forever**?* ***Eternity**?* Maybe just ***Time*** (No, wait - that's already been taken as a magazine title! :)

Comment: As a new user, it may be worth pointing out that adding a GIF that isn't relevant is an easy way to get your question downvoted.  Stack Exchange isn't Twitter. :)

Comment: @JesseWilliams Yep. Think you don’t have the rep quite yet to make unsupervised edits, but you can still recommend such edits without requiring OP to take action on their own. I think every approved edit nets you +2 pts and also works towards some specific and relatively rare badges.

Comment: @DanBron - Yeah, just always good to also point it out to new users.  Thanks for taking care of the edit, though.

Comment: I didn't know what file to add for this question. Newbie error

Answer (score 2):

Past + present + future =

> ***[always](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/always)***
>
> 1. At all times; invariably: *always late.*
> 2. For all time; forever: *They will always be friends.*
> 3. At any time; in any event: *You can always resign if you're unhappy.*
>
> *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language,*